# Google+ API Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions

Tags: java, api

I am running the YouTubeSample given on the google developers website. I have no errors in the code and my imports appear to be fine. But when I run the project I get the aforementioned error.

I have done some searches but to be honest I have been unable to work out what the problem is. I have already tried importing an external jar guava but it didn't help.

Any help is appreciated. Here is the full class

```
package com.pengilleys.googlesamples;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.JsonCParser;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

public class YouTubeSample {

 public static class VideoFeed {
@Key List<Video> items;
}

public static class Video {
@Key String title;
@Key String description;
@Key Player player;
}

public static class Player {
@Key("default") String defaultUrl;
}

public static class YouTubeUrl extends GenericUrl {
@Key final String alt = "jsonc";
@Key String author;
@Key("max-results") Integer maxResults;

YouTubeUrl(String url) {
  super(url);
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// set up the HTTP request factory
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
HttpRequestFactory factory = transport.createRequestFactory(new    HttpRequestInitializer() {

  @Override
  public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
    // set the parser
    JsonCParser parser = new JsonCParser();
    parser.jsonFactory = jsonFactory;
    request.addParser(parser);
    // set up the Google headers
    GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
    headers.setApplicationName("Google-YouTubeSample/1.0");
    headers.gdataVersion = "2";
    request.headers = headers;
  }
});
// build the YouTube URL
YouTubeUrl url = new YouTubeUrl("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos");
url.author = "searchstories";
url.maxResults = 2;
// build the HTTP GET request
HttpRequest request = factory.buildGetRequest(url);
// execute the request and the parse video feed
VideoFeed feed = request.execute().parseAs(VideoFeed.class);
for (Video video : feed.items) {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Video title: " + video.title);
  System.out.println("Description: " + video.description);
  System.out.println("Play URL: " + video.player.defaultUrl);
}
```

}
    }

Answer (score 7):

The [setup documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Dependencies) gives a list of dependencies:

> Depending on the application you are building, you may also need these dependencies:
>
> - [Apache HTTP Client version 4.0.3](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
> - [Google Guava version r09](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)
> - [Jackson version 1.6.7](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
> - [Google GSON version 1.6](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

In this case, it looks like it's Guava which is missing. I don't know what you mean about "exporting" Guava, but if you include the Guava r09 jar file in the classpath when you're running the code, it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

what's the extra `);` for above the `// build the YouTube URL`  and did you mean to close `main` on that line?

Comment: It is the matching close for `transport.createRequestFactory(`. It is confusing because the code is badly formatted

Comment: oh... thanks! I was just curious.  I would have made that a comment if i had enough rep to leave comments